# CCAction help in Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am making a game with Cocos2d. Currently I have enemies that move in 75 pixel intervals every 3 seconds. I would like them to shoot. By this I mean that I would like the enemies to move, then stop, then shoot, then repeat. But obviously, you know that there is not a CCShootAction. I have the shoot method in the Enemies.m class, but it lies dormant there. How can I use it to make the enemy shoot, without moving it to the HelloWorldLayer.m class? Any help is appreciated. Thank You!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Repeat Action and a CCCallFuncO action to send the object of the enemy.

In some func of the HelloWorldLayer.m class:

```
   - (void) someFunc
    {
         // ...

            Enemy* enemy; // your enemy object
         // ...

            CCMoveBy* move = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:3 position:ccp(75,0)];
            CCCallFuncO* shot = [CCCallFuncO actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(shoot:) object:enemy];
            CCSequence* sequ = [CCSequence actions:move,shot,nil];
            CCRepeatForever* repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:sequ];
            [sprite runAction:repeat]; // your enemy sprite here
        }

        - (void) shoot: (id) obj
        {
            Enemy* enemy = (Enemy*)obj;
            [enemy shoot];
        }
```

From the shoot selector you can call some method from that object

Comment: that seems like it should work, but sadly it doesn't. Do you have any troubleshooting tips?